# Composer install package with dev dependencies

Tags: php, laravel

How do I install a composer package with dev dependencies?

So for example:

When I have this package:

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-demo-mode

And I run:

```
composer require spatie/laravel-demo-mode
```

The tests folder is not installed?!

Comment: Did you publish the config file? And did you put Route::demoAccess('/demo'); in your routes file?

Comment: Yes, but that has nothing to do with my question. I want to contribute but the test folder is not there when I run `composer require spatie/laravel-demo-mode`

Comment: When you run composer, you get the files from the composer servers, not from github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short you don't (ever). If you want to contribute, you need to set up new Laravel project and set up composer to autoload your version of package, <strike>either from your fork or</strike> from somewhere on your disk. And when you do that you are just using your version of the package (again without the possibility to run packages's tests).

In order to run tests of the package you need to change directory to the root of the package and install its dependencies (`$ composer install`), after you've done that you may run `$ phpunit`.

---

What I am usually doing in when I want to contribute is:

- have empty Laravel project ready (unversioned)
- have `packages` folder in root
- in that `packages` folder I usually do `$ git clone <repo fork>` (It may be more than one package at once)
- in case I want to run package's tests I do `$ composer install` and `$ phpunit` (your IDE may squeak at you about duplicate definitions but you may ignore it)
- improve and test the code of package in packages folder
- test your changes "live" on Laravel project right-away

**composer.json** may look like:

```
...
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Vendor\\Package\\": "packages/path-to-src/"
    }
},
...
```

You may find useful this example repo I use https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable-example to demonstrate how to work with package I maintain. Mainly take a look at **folder structure** and **composer.json.**

There may be better ways on how to do contributing but I have only found (and developed) this one.

---

If I have small changes in mind (like typo, or just return type or whatever is "small") I do change package within vendor folder, and see if it breaks anything; after that I fork package source and edit the change right in the Github's web interface. To clean up just run `$ composer install/update` from root folder of your Laravel project.

Comment: Thanks really helpful!

Comment: @Jenssen I did edit my answer (bottom part) that may be better for you if you do tiny changes.